# TableRow doesn't match the layout

Tags: android, xml, button, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to make a tableLayout's row to fill the whole layout's width but it stays like its matching the content.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nyc_skyline"

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/menu_btn"
                android:src="@drawable/lines7" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="text"
                android:id="@+id/bubble_header"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_black_48dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:longClickable="false" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I attached a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Q7fjnwq17FczlaMnBsbDhySnc) .
I'm a begginer using android studio.

how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this.

`android:layout_margin="6dp"`

Comment: I removed it but nothing happened